# Is there any way to remove this nullobject reference error? I am trying to open a bottom dialog from scanner activity

Tags: android

1. Error:

   ```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.swiftpass, PID: 16875
        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.swiftpass.ScanPopUpDialog.setPrompt(ScanPopUpDialog.java:47)
            at com.example.swiftpass.ScanQrActivity$MyImageAnalyzer.readerBarcodeData(ScanQrActivity.java:170)
            at com.example.swiftpass.ScanQrActivity$MyImageAnalyzer.access$200(ScanQrActivity.java:109)
            at com.example.swiftpass.ScanQrActivity$MyImageAnalyzer$3.onSuccess(ScanQrActivity.java:142)
            at com.example.swiftpass.ScanQrActivity$MyImageAnalyzer$3.onSuccess(ScanQrActivity.java:138)
            at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.0:4)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
   ```
2. XML Code:

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_close"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_close">
            </ImageView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_type"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:text="@string/qr_type"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_black"
                android:textSize="20dp">
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_prompt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:text="@string/qr_prompt"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                android:textSize="18dp">
            </TextView>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
   ```
3. Bottom dialog java:

   package com.example.swiftpass;

   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.ImageView;
   import android.widget.TextView;
   import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
   import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

   import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialogFragment;

   public class ScanPopUpDialog extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

   ```
    //Declaration of Variables

    TextView type;
    TextView prompt;
    ImageView close;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up_dialog, container, false);

        type = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_type);
        prompt = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_prompt);
        close = view.findViewById(R.id.img_close);
        close.setOnClickListener(this::OnClick);
        return view;
    }

    //This function will listen to button clicks and will call certain functions according to what is pressed by the user
    private void OnClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.img_close:
                dismiss();
                break;
            case R.id.txt_prompt:
                break;
        }
    }

    public void setPrompt(String type, String prompt){
        this.type.setText(type);
        this.prompt.setText(prompt);

        if (type == "TEXT"){
            this.prompt.setOnClickListener(this::OnClick);
        }
    }
   ```

   }
4. Scanner Activity java:

   package com.example.swiftpass;

   import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
   import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector;
   import androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis;
   import androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture;
   import androidx.camera.core.ImageProxy;
   import androidx.camera.core.Preview;
   import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider;
   import androidx.camera.view.PreviewView;
   import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
   import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
   import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;

   import android.Manifest;
   import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
   import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
   import android.graphics.Point;
   import android.graphics.Rect;
   import android.media.Image;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.util.Size;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
   import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
   import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
   import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
   import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;
   import com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.Barcode;
   import com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.BarcodeScanner;
   import com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.BarcodeScannerOptions;
   import com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.BarcodeScanning;
   import com.google.mlkit.vision.common.InputImage;

   import java.util.List;
   import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
   import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
   import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

   public class ScanQrActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   ```
    //Declaration of Variables

    private ListenableFuture cameraProviderFuture;
    private ExecutorService cameraExecutor;
    private PreviewView previewView;
    private MyImageAnalyzer analyzer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_qr);

        //Assigning of widgets and Setting up of listeners
        initializeScan();


        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(ScanQrActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ScanQrActivity.this, new String [] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 101);
                    }else{
                        ProcessCameraProvider processCameraProvider = (ProcessCameraProvider) cameraProviderFuture.get();
                        bindPreview(processCameraProvider);
                    }
                }catch (ExecutionException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == 101 && grantResults.length > 0){
            ProcessCameraProvider processCameraProvider = null;
            try {
                processCameraProvider = (ProcessCameraProvider) cameraProviderFuture.get();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            bindPreview(processCameraProvider);
        }
    }

    private void bindPreview(ProcessCameraProvider processCameraProvider) {

        Preview preview = new Preview.Builder().build();
        CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK).build();
        preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.getSurfaceProvider());
        ImageCapture imageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder().build();
        ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis = new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                .setTargetResolution(new Size(1280, 720))
                .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                .build();
        imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(cameraExecutor, analyzer);
        processCameraProvider.unbindAll();
        processCameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this,cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture, imageAnalysis);
    }

    public class MyImageAnalyzer implements ImageAnalysis.Analyzer{
        private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
        private ScanPopUpDialog bottomDialog;

        public MyImageAnalyzer(FragmentManager fragmentManager){
            this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
            bottomDialog = new ScanPopUpDialog();
        }

        @Override
        public void analyze(@NonNull ImageProxy imageProxy) {
             scanBarcode(imageProxy);
        }

        private void scanBarcode(ImageProxy imageProxy) {

            BarcodeScannerOptions options =
                    new BarcodeScannerOptions.Builder()
                            .setBarcodeFormats(
                                    Barcode.FORMAT_QR_CODE)
                            .build();

            @SuppressLint("UnsafeExperimentalUsageError") Image mediaImage = imageProxy.getImage();
            assert mediaImage != null;
            InputImage inputImage =
                    InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, imageProxy.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees());

            BarcodeScanner scanner = BarcodeScanning.getClient(options);
            Task<List<Barcode>> result = scanner.process(inputImage)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Barcode>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(List<Barcode> barcodes) {
                            // Task completed successfully
                            readerBarcodeData(barcodes);
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            // Task failed with an exception
                            // ...
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<List<Barcode>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<List<Barcode>> task) {
                            imageProxy.close();
                        }
                    });
        }

        private void readerBarcodeData(List<Barcode> barcodes) {
            for (Barcode barcode: barcodes) {
                Rect bounds = barcode.getBoundingBox();
                Point[] corners = barcode.getCornerPoints();

                String rawValue = barcode.getRawValue();
                int valueType = barcode.getValueType();
                switch (valueType){
                    case Barcode.TYPE_TEXT:
                        bottomDialog.setPrompt(rawValue, "CLICK TO CONFIRM");
                        break;
                    case Barcode.TYPE_CALENDAR_EVENT:
                        bottomDialog.setPrompt("Calendar Event", "Unsupported Type");
                        break;
                    case Barcode.TYPE_CONTACT_INFO:
                        bottomDialog.setPrompt("Contact Info", "Unsupported Type");
                        break;
                    case Barcode.TYPE_DRIVER_LICENSE:
                        bottomDialog.setPrompt("Driver's License", "Unsupported Type");
                        break;
                    case Barcode.TYPE_EMAIL:
                        bottomDialog.setPrompt("E-mail", "Unsupported Type");
                        break;
                    case Barcode.TYPE_GEO:
                        bottomDialog.setPrompt("Location", "Unsupported Type");
                        break;
                    case Barcode.TYPE_ISBN:
                        bottomDialog.setPrompt("Book Number", "Unsupported Type");
                        break;
                    case Barcode.TYPE_PHONE:
                        bottomDialog.setPrompt("Phone", "Unsupported Type");
                        break;
                    case Barcode.TYPE_PRODUCT:
                        bottomDialog.setPrompt("Product", "Unsupported Type");
                        break;
                    case Barcode.TYPE_SMS:
                        bottomDialog.setPrompt("SMS", "Unsupported Type");
                        break;
                    case Barcode.TYPE_URL:
                        bottomDialog.setPrompt("Link", "Unsupported Type");
                        break;
                    case Barcode.TYPE_WIFI:
                        bottomDialog.setPrompt("Wi-Fi", "Unsupported Type");
                        break;
                    default:
                        bottomDialog.setPrompt("Uknown", "Uknown Type");
                }
                if (!bottomDialog.isAdded()){
                    bottomDialog.show(fragmentManager, "");
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private void initializeScan() {
        previewView = findViewById(R.id.previewView);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(1024,1024);
        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);
        analyzer = new MyImageAnalyzer(getSupportFragmentManager());
    }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 1):

I solved it and the code goes like this:

```
package com.example.swiftpass;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialogFragment;


public class ScanPopUpDialog extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    //Declaration of Variables

    TextView type;
    TextView prompt;
    ImageView close;
    String stringType;
    String stringPrompt;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up_dialog, container, false);

        type = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_type);
        type.setText(getStringType());
        prompt = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_prompt);
        prompt.setText(getStringPrompt());
        if (stringPrompt == "CLICK TO CONFIRM"){
            prompt.setOnClickListener(this::OnClick);
        }
        close = view.findViewById(R.id.img_close);
        close.setOnClickListener(this::OnClick);
        return view;
    }

    //This function will listen to button clicks and will call certain functions according to what is pressed by the user
    private void OnClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.img_close:
                dismiss();
                break;
            case R.id.txt_prompt:
                break;
        }
    }

    public void setDialog(String type, String prompt){
        /**
         * This method is public because it is being called fron the scan qr activity
         * this will set the value for the objects stringType and stringPrompt
         * this does not return any value thus, the values will be accessed through
         * get method
         */
        stringType = type;
        stringPrompt = prompt;
    }

    /**
     *These methods are used to access the value set by the setDialog method
     *
     */
    private String getStringType(){
        return stringType;
    }

    private String getStringPrompt(){
        return stringPrompt;
    }
}
```